# CSS definitions in style tag are not loaded in mobile browser

Tags: css, angularjs, responsive-design, mobile-website, single-page-application

I'm on a single-page responsive application using angularjs and php where I embedded all my JavaScript and CSS codes in `<script>` and `<style>` tags respectively. It's working perfectly on desktop browser but it has funny behaviors in mobile browsers. What can I do to solve this problem?

The page structure is shown below.

```
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en" > 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="fragment" content="!" />
    <title>Project Title</title>
    <style>
        .autocomplete-suggestions { border: 1px solid #999; background: #FFF; cursor: default; overflow: auto; -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.64); -moz-box-shadow: 1px 4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.64); box-shadow: 1px 4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.64); }
        .autocomplete-suggestion { padding: 2px 5px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
        .autocomplete-selected { background: #F0F0F0; }
        .autocomplete-suggestions strong { font-weight: normal; color: #3399FF; }
        .alert-box .dismiss {
            font-size: 1.375em;
            padding: 5px 4px 4px;
            line-height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0.4375em;
            right: 0.3125em;
            color: #333333;
            opacity: 0.3; }
            .alert-box .dismiss:hover, .alert-box .dismiss:focus {
              opacity: 0.5; }
        .top-bar {
            background:none;
            height:45px;
            line-height: 35px;
            padding-left: 1%;
            padding-right: 1%;
            padding-top: 3px;
            z-index:100;
        }
        .top-bar.expanded .title-area {
            background:none; 
            padding:5px;
        }
        .top-bar .name h1 a {
            font-size: 1.3em;
        }
        .top-bar-section {
            background: none;
        }
        .top-bar-section ul {
            background: none;
        }
        .top-bar-section ul li > a {  
            background: none;
        }
        .top-bar-section ul li:hover > a {
            background: none;
            color: white; }
        .top-bar-section ul li.active > a {
            background: none;
            color: white; }
        .top-bar-section [role="separator"] {
            border-bottom: solid 1px;
            border-top: solid 1px #003366;}
        .top-bar-section .has-form {
            background:none;}
        .top-bar-section .has-form a{
            background:url("/img/tophd.png");} 
        .top-bar .toggle-topbar a {
            font-size: 0.8125em;

            height: 35px;
            line-height: 35px; }
        .inline-list{
            margin-left: 10%;
            margin-top: 7px;

        }
        .inline-list > li > a {
            color: #000;
            font-size: 0.8125em;

        }
        .inline-list > li > a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .shadow-5{
            -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ccc;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ccc;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ccc;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ccc;
            border:none;
        }
        .shadow-2{
            -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ccc;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ccc;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ccc;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ccc;
            border:none;
        }
        .margin10{
            margin-left: 10%;
            margin-right: 10%;
        }
        .sliderimage{
            width: 100%;

        }
        .headercontent{
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 55px;
            /*color:url("/img/tophd.png");*/
        }
        .pull-left{float: left;}
        .content-1{
            font-size: 0.8125em;
        }
        .pad10{
            padding: 10px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
        .footer{ z-index: 99999; bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; 
                position: absolute; bottom: 0px; 
        }
        .bgwhite{
            background: #fff;
            margin-bottom: 1px;
        }
        .pull-right{float: right; }
        .clearfix{
            clear: both;
        }
        .padright10{padding-right: 20%}
        .bgnone{background: none;}
        @media only screen and (min-width: 58.75em){
            .top-bar {
                background:url("/img/tophd.png");
            }
            .top-bar.expanded {
                background:url("/img/tophd.png"); }
            .top-bar-section li.hover > a:not(.button) {
                background:url("/img/tophd.png");
                color: white;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .top-bar-section li a:not(.button) {
                padding: 0 15px;
                line-height: 35px;
                background:none; }
            .top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
                background:url("/img/tophd.png"); }

        .companylogo{
            height: 150px;
        }
        .icon{
            height: 20px;
        }
        .width100{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .ftbold{font-weight: bold}
        .large-icon{ height: 40px;}
        .user-meeting{height: 40px;}
        .center{margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}
        .meeting-user-active{
            border: 2px solid #0099ff;
        }
        .meeting-user{
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
        }
        .marginbuttom5{
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        ul.right li{background:none}
        ul.right li a{background:none;}
        .content1{
            background:#006377;
            width:100%;
            text-align:center;
            margin-top: -10px;
            padding-top:10px;}
        .content1 h3{width:inherit}
        .fwhite{color:#fff;
        }
        .fgreyblue {color:#00C5F4;}
        .feature-box-color {color:#00C5F4;}

        .fontlight{font-weight:lighter;}
        .font16{font-size:16px}
        .font18{font-size:18px}
        .font10{font-size:10px;}
        .font20{font-size:20px}
        .font24{font-size:24px}
        .font30{font-size:30px}
        .font12{font-size:12px;}
        .content2{text-align:center}
        .feature-box{width:174px; height:181px;min-width:174px; min-height:181px;max-width:174px; max-height:181px; padding:10px; background:#333333; color: #00C5F4 !important; margin:1%; float:left; }
        .feature-box:hover{background:#00C5F4; color: #000000;}
        .feature-box:hover > .feature-img{background-image:url(/img/features-bg-sprite-hover-compressed.png)}
        .feature-box:hover > .feature-box-color {color:#000;}
        .feature-img{width:98px; height:74px;min-width:98px; min-height:74px;max-width:98px; max-height:74px; margin:20px auto; background-image:url(/img/features-bg-sprite-compressed.png)}
        .feature-img-1{background-position:0px 0px; }
        .feature-img-2{background-position: 98px 0px; }
        .feature-img-3{background-position: 196px 0px; }
        .feature-img-4{background-position: 294px 0px; }
        .feature-img-5{background-position: 391px 0px; }
        .feature-img-6{background-position: 490px 0px; }
        .feature-img-7{background-position: 588px 0px; }
        .feature-img-8{background-position: 686px 0px; }
        .header{background: url("/img/tophd.png") repeat-x #006D92; }
        .feature-container{max-width: 790px; margin: 0 auto}
        .index-banner{padding: 0 70px;}

        @media only screen {
            .feature-container{max-width: 790px; margin: 0 auto}
            .index-banner{padding: 0 0;}
        } /* Define mobile styles */

        @media (max-width: 756px) {
            .feature-container{max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto}
            .index-banner{padding: 0 10px;}
        } /* max-width 640px, mobile-only styles, use when QAing mobile issues */
        @media (max-width: 1060px) {
            .feature-container{max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto}
            .index-banner{padding: 0 20px;}
        } /* max-width 640px, mobile-only styles, use when QAing mobile issues */
        @media (max-width: 555px) {
            .index-banner{padding: 0 10px;}
            .feature-container{max-width: 400px; margin: 0 auto}
        } /* max-width 640px, mobile-only styles, use when QAing mobile issues */
        @media (max-width: 363px) {
            .index-banner{padding: 0 0;}
            .feature-container{max-width: 200px; margin: 0 auto}
        } /* max-width 640px, mobile-only styles, use when QAing mobile issues */

        @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) { } /* min-width 641px, medium screens */

        @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) { } /* min-width 641px and max-width 1024px, use when QAing tablet-only issues */
        .margin10{margin-top:10px}
        .paddingleft{padding-left:0px}
        .content3{
            background:#f1f1f1;
            width:100%;
            text-align:center;
            padding-top:10px;}
        .content4{
            background:#333333;
            color:#fff;
            width:100%;
            text-align:center;
            padding-top:0px; height:32px; overflow:hidden; position:absoluteb; bottom:0px;}
        .content4 h5{color:#fff; font-size:12px;}
        .content4 .inline-list li a {color:#fff; font-size:12px;}
        .width80{min-width:70%; width:84.2%; float:left}
        .width20{min-width:100px; width:15.8%; float:left; background:#006077;}
        .logo-img{margin-top: -20px; }
        .copyright-info{color:#fff; font-size:12px; text-align: center}
        .text-center{text-align: center}

        .bgBlue{background:#37414B;}
        .padding0{padding:0px;}
        .margin0{margin:0px;}
        .section-container.accordion > section > .title,
        .section-container.accordion > .section > .title {
            background-color: #000;
            border: solid 1px #00627F;
        }
        .section-container.accordion > section > .title a,
        .section-container.accordion > .section > .title a {
            padding: 0.9375em;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 0.875em;
            background: none; }
        .section-container.accordion > section > .title:hover,
        .section-container.accordion > .section > .title:hover {
            background-color: #666; }
        .section-container.accordion > section > .content,
        .section-container.accordion > .section > .content {
            padding: 0.9375em;
            background-color: #37414B;
            border: solid 1px #00627F;
            color:#fff; }


        .section-container.accordion > section.active > .title,
        .section-container.accordion > .section.active > .title {
            background: none; }

        .section-container.accordion > section.active > .title a,
        .section-container.accordion > .section.active > .title a {
            color: #fff; }
        .section-container.accordion {
            border-top: 1px solid #00627F; }
        .section-container.accordion > section > .title,
        .section-container.accordion > .section > .title {
            background-color: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: solid 1px #00627F; }
        .section-container.accordion > section > .title a,
        .section-container.accordion > .section > .title a {
            color: #fff;
        }
        .section-container.accordion > section > .title:hover,
        .section-container.accordion > .section > .title:hover {
            background-color: none; }
        .section-container.accordion > section > .content,
        .section-container.accordion > .section > .content {
            padding: 0.9375em;
            background-color: none;
            border: solid 1px #00627F; }
        .section-container.accordion > section.active > .title,
        .section-container.accordion > .section.active > .title {
            background: none; }
        .section-container.accordion > section.active > .title a,
        .section-container.accordion > .section.active > .title a {
            color: #fff; }
        .fcolorWhite{color:#fff;}
        .checkbox{color:#fff;}
        .teamsearch{background:none; color:#000; width:92%;}
        .profilepic{width:120px; padding:5px; background:#00C4FD;}
        .profiledetail{color:#37404B; font-weight:lighter; font-size:12px;}
        .pad5{padding:5px;}
        .padLeft10{padding-left:10px;}
        .padLeft30{padding-left:30px;}
        .bgBlue-wrap{background:#00627F; color:#fff; font-size:12px;}
        .profilerow{background:#37414B;}
        .profilesearch{background:#EFF2EF; max-height:30px; overflow:hidden;}
        .margin-10{margin-top:-10px;}     
        .magtop5{margin-top:10px}
        .bordernone{border:none;}
        .midcenter{min-height:100px; border:#21CCF3 2px solid; width:70%; margin:0px auto; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:20px; padding:30px; text-align:center;}
        .logo{height:35px;}
        .help{height:25px;}


        input[type="text"],
        input[type="password"],
        input[type="date"],
        input[type="datetime"],
        input[type="datetime-local"],
        input[type="month"],
        input[type="week"],
        input[type="email"],
        input[type="number"],
        input[type="search"],
        input[type="tel"],
        input[type="time"],
        input[type="url"],
        textarea {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
            background-color: white;
            font-family: inherit;
            border: 1px solid #cccccc;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
            display: block;
            font-size: 0.875em;
            /*margin: 0 0 1em 0;*/
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding: 0.5em;
            height: 2.3125em;
            width: 100%;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.45s, border-color 0.45s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow 0.45s, border-color 0.45s ease-in-out;
            transition: box-shadow 0.45s, border-color 0.45s ease-in-out; }
        input[type="text"]:focus,
        input[type="password"]:focus,
        input[type="date"]:focus,
        input[type="datetime"]:focus,
        input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
        input[type="month"]:focus,
        input[type="week"]:focus,
        input[type="email"]:focus,
        input[type="number"]:focus,
        input[type="search"]:focus,
        input[type="tel"]:focus,
        input[type="time"]:focus,
        input[type="url"]:focus,
        textarea:focus {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #00CFF5;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #00CFF5;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px #00CFF5;
            border-color: #00CFF5;
            background-color: #fff;
            outline: none;}
        input[type="text"][disabled],
        input[type="password"][disabled],
        input[type="date"][disabled],
        input[type="datetime"][disabled],
        input[type="datetime-local"][disabled],
        input[type="month"][disabled],
        input[type="week"][disabled],
        input[type="email"][disabled],
        input[type="number"][disabled],
        input[type="search"][disabled],
        input[type="tel"][disabled],
        input[type="time"][disabled],
        input[type="url"][disabled],
        textarea[disabled] {
            background-color: #dddddd; }

        /* Adjust margin for form elements below */
        input[type="file"],
        input[type="checkbox"],
        input[type="radio"],
        select {
            margin: 0 0 1em 0; }
        .roundButton{
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .fontbold{font-weight:bold;}
        .vleftBar{position:absolute; top:0px; padding-top:45px; left:0px; min-height:100%; width:23%;  }

        .margin-20{margin-left:24%;}
        .padding-left-20{padding-left:24%;}
        .top-bar .name h1  {
            margin-top:-5px;
        }
        .vrightBar1{width:76%}
        @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){
            .vleftBar{position:fixed; top:0px; padding-top:45px; left:0px; min-height:100%; width:220px;  z-index:-10 }
            .margin-20{margin-left:223px;}
            .padding-left-20{padding-left:223px;;}
            .logo{height:30px; }
            .site-title{font-size:20px; }
            .top-bar .name h1  {
                margin-top:-8px;
            }
            .teamsearch{background:#37414B; color:#fff; width:400px;}
            vrightBar1{width:60%;}
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){vrightBar1{width:40%;}
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
            .vleftBar{position:relative; min-width:100%; min-height:100px;  top:0px; }
            .margin-20{margin-left:0px;}
            .padding-left-20{padding-left:0px}
            .logo{height:20px; }
            .site-title{font-size:16px; }
            .top-bar .name h1  {
                margin-top:-8px;
            }
            .bgBlue-wrap{float:left; margin-left:10px;}
            vrightBar1{ min-width:100%; float:left;}

        }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
            h4 {
                font-size: 1.0em;
            }
        }
        .content-header{padding:10px;}
        .nonetextshadow{
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
            background-color: white;
            font-family: inherit;
            border: none;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);


        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
            .teamsearch{background:none; color:#000; width:90%;}}

        @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){
            .teamsearch{background:none; color:#000; width:87%;}}
        @media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
            .teamsearch{background:none; color:#000; width:82%;}}
        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
            .teamsearch{background:none; color:#000; width:80%;}}
        .button-dialog{background:#00627F; text-align:center;}
        .progress-cont{background-color: #666;}
        @media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
            .sm-fix-modal{min-width:300px;}}
        .date-complete{color:#F00; font-size:11px}
        .date-uncomplete{color:#00C5F4; font-size:11px}
        .date{color:#666; font-size:11px}
        .profilebg { min-height:147px; height:150px; overflow:hidden; min-width:100%; background: #e8e7e7 url(/img/profile-bg.jpg) repeat;}
        .circle{
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
            border-radius: 100px;
            -moz-border-radius: 100px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
            background:#fff;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .notification{
            min-height:30px;
            min-width:30px;
            height:30px;
            width:30px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            -moz-border-radius: 30px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
            background:#ff0000;
            overflow:hidden;
            padding:3px;
        }
        .fcolordarkblue{color:#00617F}
        .profile-active{background:#00C4FD;}
        .bgDarkBlue{background:#00627F;}
        .bgGreen{background:#19BA9A;}
        .fcolorgreen{color:#19BA9A}
        .fcolorgreen td{color:#19BA9A}
        .bgRed{background:#F78A9D;}
        .fcolorred{color:#F78A9D;}
        .fcolorred td{color:#F78A9D;}
        .message-icon{height:50px;}

        .input-ajax-validate-loading, .input-ajax-validate-loading:focus{background-image: url(/img/ajax-loader.gif); background-position: right; background-repeat: no-repeat}
        .input-ajax-validate-success, .input-ajax-validate-success:focus{background-image: url(/img/validated-ok.png); background-position: right; background-repeat: no-repeat}
        .input-ajax-validate-error, .input-ajax-validate-error:focus{background-image: url(/img/validated-error.png); background-position: right; background-repeat: no-repeat}
        .form-control{margin-bottom: 1em}
        tr {vertical-align: top}
        .pl0{padding-left: 0px;}
        .ml10{padding-left: 10px;}
        .user-icon{width: 64px; height: 64px;}
        .mb10{margin-bottom: 10px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div as-header></div>
    <div as-left-bar></div>
    <div as-alert></div>
    <div ng-view id="ng-view" style="padding-top: 3px;  margin-top: -10px; padding-bottom:33px;">
        <div style="width: 80%; margin: 70px auto;text-align: center">
            <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"/>
            <div style="height: 15px; width: 40%; border: #333 solid 2px; margin: 0 auto;" >
                <div id="loadingBar" style="background: #006077; width: 0%; height: 11px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div as-footer></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
       <?php echo $javaScript; ?>; 
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What can we do if you don't show us the interested part of code?

Comment: I just wonder, does `angularjs` works on mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for various comment, the problem is a weird one. However I've got to the root of the matter. The problem lies with conflicting CSS media queries. The media query CSS definition for mobile devices is broken somewhere and it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

not very sure, but you certainly are getting affected by the lack of below `meta`, you have added one i saw, update it to the below and check...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: expecting possible downvotes but would appreciate if anyone drops a comment before downvoting!! :)

Comment: The HTML given has the `meta`. The scaling attributes are of course advisable but not required.

Answer (score 0):

Generally mobile browsers has special events that you should keep in mind:

- touchstart
- touchend
- touchcancel
- touchleave
- touchmove

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events)

if the problem is with the styling and css you should consider using media queries for best fit to different screen sizes (responsive design). you can read more about it [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-create-media-queries-in-responsive-web-design/#.)

Hope this helps, even though it is very general. if you paste the actual css and script and be more specific about the problematic behavior it would be more efficient.

Comment: The style definition echoed into the page is shown below. I use foundation framework for the project I think that should have solved the media query issue

Comment: Could you describe the problem? I see you did not post the JavaScript -if it is a functionality problem or a problem that occurs only after a certain action that code would be necessary as well.

Comment: The only problem experienced is that the CSS code in the style seems to be not interpreted by mobile browser except for the inline styles. It behaves like a page without CSS. See the original post for the CSS

Comment: Make sure you have `<!doctype html>` at the top of the html. also you can add `type="text/css"` to the style tag.